# Mapbox marker personalisation

Tags: ios, swift, mapbox, mapbox-ios

Does anybody know how I can create personalised mapbox markers like these using different annotation images. At the moment I can only figure out how to get one annotation into my project. Is there a way to add multiple annotations?

[image]

I have started here https://docs.mapbox.com/ios/maps/examples/annotation-view-image/ but am unsure as where to go next.

thanks

Comment: What are your specific problems? The code link you provide seems to have everything you need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you must add some point annotations to your map and then display image or view for each annotation. Annotation will be placed on coordinate, so you must create some random coordinates.

You can add point annotations to the map like this:

```swift
// Specify coordinates for our annotations.
let coordinates = [
    CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 0, longitude: 33),
    CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 0, longitude: 66),
    CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 0, longitude: 99)
]

// Fill an array with point annotations and add it to the map.
var pointAnnotations = [MGLPointAnnotation]()
for coordinate in coordinates {
    let point = MGLPointAnnotation()
    point.coordinate = coordinate
    point.title = "\(coordinate.latitude), \(coordinate.longitude)"
    pointAnnotations.append(point)
}

mapView.addAnnotations(pointAnnotations)
```

This code is taken from this example: [Annotation views](https://docs.mapbox.com/ios/maps/examples/annotation-views/)

Then you must conform to `MGLMapViewDelegate` in order to call `mapView(_:imageFor:)` delegate method:

```swift
// MGLMapViewDelegate method for adding static images to point annotations
func mapView(_ mapView: MGLMapView, imageFor annotation: MGLAnnotation) -> MGLAnnotationImage? {
    
    let annotationImage: MGLAnnotationImage
    let annotationImageCocktail = mapView.dequeueReusableAnnotationImage(withIdentifier: "cocktail")
    let annotationImageSushi = mapView.dequeueReusableAnnotationImage(withIdentifier: "sushi")
    
    switch annotation.coordinate.longitude {
    case 33:
        annotationImage = annotationImageCocktail ?? MGLAnnotationImage(image: UIImage(named: "cocktail")!, reuseIdentifier: "cocktail")
    case 66:
        annotationImage = annotationImageSushi ?? MGLAnnotationImage(image: UIImage(named: "sushi")!, reuseIdentifier: "sushi")
    case 99:
        annotationImage = annotationImageCocktail ??  MGLAnnotationImage(image: UIImage(named: "cocktail")!, reuseIdentifier: "cocktail")
    default:
        annotationImage = annotationImageSushi ?? MGLAnnotationImage(image: UIImage(named: "sushi")!, reuseIdentifier: "sushi")
    }
    
    return annotationImage
}
```

And here is the whole code:

```swift
import Mapbox

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Method for displaying map view
        let mapView = MGLMapView(frame: view.bounds)
        mapView.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleWidth, .flexibleHeight]
        mapView.styleURL = MGLStyle.darkStyleURL
        mapView.tintColor = .lightGray
        mapView.centerCoordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 0, longitude: 66)
        mapView.zoomLevel = 2
        mapView.delegate = self
        view.addSubview(mapView)

        // Specify coordinates for our annotations.
        let coordinates = [
            CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 0, longitude: 33),
            CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 0, longitude: 66),
            CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 0, longitude: 99)
        ]

        // Fill an array with point annotations and add it to the map.
        var pointAnnotations = [MGLPointAnnotation]()
        for coordinate in coordinates {
            let point = MGLPointAnnotation()
            point.coordinate = coordinate
            point.title = "\(coordinate.latitude), \(coordinate.longitude)"
            pointAnnotations.append(point)
        }

        mapView.addAnnotations(pointAnnotations)
    }

}

extension ViewController: MGLMapViewDelegate {
    
    // MGLMapViewDelegate method for adding static images to point annotations
    func mapView(_ mapView: MGLMapView, imageFor annotation: MGLAnnotation) -> MGLAnnotationImage? {

        let annotationImage: MGLAnnotationImage
        let annotationImageCocktail = mapView.dequeueReusableAnnotationImage(withIdentifier: "cocktail")
        let annotationImageSushi = mapView.dequeueReusableAnnotationImage(withIdentifier: "sushi")

        switch annotation.coordinate.longitude {
        case 33:
            annotationImage = annotationImageCocktail ?? MGLAnnotationImage(image: UIImage(named: "cocktail")!, reuseIdentifier: "cocktail")
        case 66:
            annotationImage = annotationImageSushi ?? MGLAnnotationImage(image: UIImage(named: "sushi")!, reuseIdentifier: "sushi")
        case 99:
            annotationImage = annotationImageCocktail ??  MGLAnnotationImage(image: UIImage(named: "cocktail")!, reuseIdentifier: "cocktail")
        default:
            annotationImage = annotationImageSushi ?? MGLAnnotationImage(image: UIImage(named: "sushi")!, reuseIdentifier: "sushi")
        }

        return annotationImage
    }
}
```

Of course you project must contation images named *cocktail* and *sushi*.

Comment: works perfectly! thank you!